# How to install Trezor Bridge?

Tags: trezor

[image: screenshot]When opening my Trezor Wallet on Chrome I get a message:

> The TREZOR Chrome Extension will be outdated soon.
>   Google will disable the functionality required by the TREZOR Chrome Extension during this year.
>   To avoid any service downtime, please install the TREZOR Bridge instead.

So I installed Trezor Bridge 2.0.14 on a MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3 but the website is still not recognizing the installation. It still says that it is not installed even though I used the Mac's Installer and everything went fine.

How can I install it properly or make the website recognize the installation?

EDIT: This is what I see after installing Bridge but then when I refresh it still says it is not installed. There are no additional icons like blocked popups or something like that in the url bar.

Comment: Chrome may be blocking the site from having access to the bridge. Check in the URL bar for any icons that aren't normally there. Those will usually have some box saying "X has been blocked" and have an option to allow it. Can you also post a screenshot of the issue that you are seeing?

Comment: Check out the [bridge wiki page](https://wiki.trezor.io/Trezor_Bridge).  It has a link to the download files [through github](https://github.com/trezor/webwallet-data/tree/master/bridge) as well as a link to the URL to check your own [bridge status](http://127.0.0.1:21325/).